Authenticate users from Windows AD trusted domain "test.com", by Windows AD trusting domain "test-dmz.com" (outgoing trust), on Linux client by SSSD
I have a primary Windows AD domain "test.com" and another Windows AD domain "test-dmz.com" for machines in a secure network and configured an outgoing trust to "test.com".
I have RHEL Linux machines that are clients of domain "test-dmz.com" (there is a network only up to this domain).
How do I configure SSSD on test-dmz.com to authenticate users from domain "test.com"?
Do i need to configure something else?
My "/etc/sssd/sssd.conf":
[sssd]
domains = test-dmz.com
services = nss, pam, sudo, ssh

[sudo]
[ssh]

[nss]
filter_groups = root
filter_users = root
reconnection_retries = 3
entry_cache_nowait_percentage = 75

[pam]

[domain/test-dmz.com]
debug_level = 5
ldap_id_mapping = True
ldap_user_objectsid = objectSid
ldap_group_objectsid = objectSid
ldap_user_primary_group = primaryGroupID
case_sensitive = false
fallback_homedir = /home/%u/
default_shell = /bin/bash

ldap_referrals = False
cache_credentials = True
enumerate = False

id_provider = ldap
auth_provider = krb5
chpass_provider = krb5
access_provider = simple

ldap_uri = ldap://dmz-vsr-dc01.test-dmz.com

ldap_id_use_start_tls = False
ldap_default_bind_dn = CN=ad_auth,OU=Services,OU=UsersTest,DC=test-dmz,DC=com
ldap_default_authtok_type = obfuscated_password
ldap_default_authtok = XXXXXX

ldap_schema = rfc2307bis
ldap_user_search_base = dc=test-dmz,dc=com
ldap_user_object_class = user
ldap_user_home_directory = unixHomeDirectory
ldap_user_principal = userPrincipalName
ldap_group_search_base = dc=test-dmz,dc=com
ldap_group_object_class = group
ldap_force_upper_case_realm = True

krb5_realm = TEST-DMZ.COM
krb5_canonicalize = False

ldap_user_name = sAMAccountName
ldap_group_member = member
simple_allow_groups = Group_unix_admins
sudo_provider = ldap
autofs_provider = ldap
resolver_provider = ldap

